# IntelliJ IDEA запускает старый код

Tags: git, intellij-idea, maven

В своем проекте я использую Maven и Git (при этом конфигурации IDEA добавлены в .gitignor). С какого-то момента при запуске проекта (Run | Shift + F10) IntelliJ IDEA перестала видеть изменения в коде (то есть при запуске выполняется старый код, без изменений).

Старая версия:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("OLD CODE");

        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Новая версия (введены изменения):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        System.out.println("OLD CODE");

        System.out.println("NEW CODE");

        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

При запуске выше приведенного кода будет следующее:

[image: Результат выполнения кода]

Вместо вывода в консоль сообщения "NEW CODE" выводится "OLD CODE".

При этом каждый раз, когда я хочу запустить код с изменениями, мне приходиться самостоятельно компилировать проект через Maven (mvn compile).

При mnv clean и последующем запуске выводится следующая ошибка:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.mycompany.test202001.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.mycompany.test202001.Main
```

Как решить эту проблему? Раньше все работало автоматически, но сейчас такое чувство, будто сбились какие-то настройки.

Доп информация:
Также примерно в это же время у меня начали слетать настройки проекта при перезапуске IDEA. IDEA теряет папку проекта. Чтобы это исправить мне приходиться делать maven reimport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема возникла из-за того, что вследствие манипуляций с git'ом из моего проекта был удален файл модуля (.iml). Обычно IntelliJ IDEA  автоматически генерирует этот файл, когда что-то случается, но не в этот раз.

В общем сгенерировать этот файл у меня не получилось, поэтому я скопировал его из другого нового проекта. При этом II сама наполнила его необходимым кодом.

После этого все перечисленные мной проблемы решились.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

У меня указанный файл был на месте но ползая по Lifecycle проекта я получил ошибку об отсутсввующей dependency на maven-compiler-plugin
в общем мне помогло добавление соответсвующего кода.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```